# Can't Print in Black and White in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, printing, epson-workforce

I am having some issues about printing archives in Windows 10.

My printer, an Epson L455, would toggle between B/W and color printing according to my preferences in Windows 7.

Nonetheless, when I bought a computer with  Windows 10 and plugged the printer in, it would then print archives only in color.

I was told I would be able to change my printer's color settings in Control Panel/Devices and Printers/Printing Preferences

However, no such option is displayed in the Printing Preferences window, as shown below

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: You have installed the Epson drivers?  What's in the advanced options?

Comment: I'm not sure about the drivers. How can I check this?

Comment: What's happens if you press advanced in the lower right?

Comment: @BrunoSchiavo - Go to the Epson website, download the drivers, install them.

Comment: Drivers are available here: http://esupport.epson-europe.com/ProductHome.aspx?lng=en-IE&data=VkjUmbBFNN26bfnNEJU7kcyzqciAkGdsmTdyH4v8Ru8U003D&tc=6

Answer (score 1):

That over simplistic dialog box indicates that proper printer driver hasn't been installed on your system. Epson's Printing Preferences should look like this :
[EPSON L455 Printing Prefences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFpfs.jpg)

To solve your problem, download and run one of these driver softwares :

- [Windows 10, 32 bit version](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=SG&CTI=4&PRN=L455%20Series&OSC=W8)
- [Windows 10, 64 bit version](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=SG&CTI=4&PRN=L455%20Series&OSC=W864)

To find out your Windows 10 version :

- right click "This PC", either the one on desktop or the one on Windows Explorer
- left click "Properties"
- look for "System Type"

Answer (score 0):

the question has been asked 2 years ago and its been necroed ??? its been answered correctly as well. Why modify it 2 years later ? just use the printer drivers instead of the Windows one.

The problem with Windows printer drivers is not because they are bad but most of the time which depends on your make of the printer, they are just meant to work. If you want more "advanced" features, you have to use the one from your manufacturer. In this case, visit the epson website and search for drivers for the Epson L455 and install the drivers for your correct operating system.

Comment: What are you going on about? Editing questions or answers is acceptable any time. There is also no *answer* but yours. I suggest you remove the chatter and focus on answering the question.

Comment: it was in the comments from the questions. it was answered multiple times.

Comment: A comment is not an answer. Unless it has an accepted *answer*, a question will keep getting pushed to the front page forever, with or without edits.